# Regex: match n characters once, after n characters

Tags: regular-expression

I am looking for a regex that matches any characters 11 times after any characters present 56 times.

example:

```
this is a long formatted line with any char. 56    timesmatchI wantNothingShouldMatchHere
```

- What I want:

  ```
  matchI want
  ```
- What I tried:

  ```
  (?<=.{56}).{11}
  ```

  but this matches `matchI want` AND `NothingShou` AND `ldMatchHere`.
- This:

  ```
  (?<=.{56}).{11}?
  ```

  yields the same.

Thank you for you help !

---

Note: This regex is aimed to be used with the `re` python module in my case

Comment: If you would explain how you want to use that RegEx (which tool do you want to use, and to what end you want to match that string), contributors might point you to other ways to accomplish the task.

Comment: Good recommendation @AdminBee, I've just added a note

Comment: See also `^.{56}\K.{11}` with perl-like regexps (`(?<=...)` is also a perl regexp operator)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work; the `^` forces the 56 characters to be at the beginning of the line:

```
(?<=^.{56}).{11}
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/41fS35/1/)

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -E 's/.{56}(.{11}).*/\1/'
```

The idea with Sed is to match the whole line and only capture the desired 11 characters. They are captured inside the `()` and the whole line is replaced by that group. See [Using \1 to keep part of the pattern](https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-4) for a more detailed explanation.

If you want to ignore lines that do not contain at least 56+11=67 characters, use

```
sed -nE 's/.{56}(.{11}).*/\1/p' file
```

Comment: I was looking only for the regex in order to use it with the re python module but this is still good to see how to make it with sed ! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using **Perl**

```perl
~$ perl -ne 'print $&."\n"  if /(?<=^.{56}).{11}/;'   file

#OR

~$ perl -ne 'print $1."\n"  if /(?<=^.{56})(.{11})/;' file
```

---

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl6)

```perl
~$ raku -ne 'put $/  if  /<?after ^.**56> .**11 /;'   file

#OR

~$ raku -ne 'put $0  if  /<?after ^ .**56> (.**11)/;' file
```

All examples return `matchI want` from the OP's sample input.

https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre
https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes